# How to put a value from a JSON replayed by an API to the body of another API post method?

Tags: android, json, http, post, android-volley

I have this project in which I get as assets some urls/endpoints/APIs. I want to take the value ("id") of a string found in each object of the JSON array ("result") of the first API and use it as a body parameter for another API call.

I have one API (Get all spots) in which I pass one token in the body and I get a JSON object with a results array (these results are some spots). Everything nice. Here is the issue: for my next API (Get spot details) I need to iterate through each object (spot) in the "result" array from the previous API response and get its "id" value. Then I will use that id as the body parameter of the Get spot details API so when I click on an item from the list of spots it will open a new activity with the details of the spot.

I tried putting the id in an ArrayList, making it static etc. but it gives me error code 500 when I try to pass the id as parameter.

```
//Get all spots result with the array in which I have to get each "id" value

{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "0dEGTxlKxh",
            "name": "27-Waam",
            "country": "India",
            "whenToGo": "APRIL",
            "isFavorite": true
        },
        {
            "id": "s7uMTLEM6g",
            "name": "2nd Bay",
            "country": "Morocco",
            "whenToGo": "AUGUST",
            "isFavorite": true
        }, ...
}
```

---

```
//The id (taken from the prvious list of spots) that I need to put in the body of Get spot details POST request

{
    "spotId": "DqeOFHedSe"
}
```

---

```
//Example of result by Get spot details API with the id of the clicked spot in the list

{
    "result": {
        "id": "DqeOFHedSe",
        "name": "Pocitas Beach",
        "longitude": -81.08,
        "latitude": -4.11,
        "windProbability": 87,
        "country": "Ecuador",
        "whenToGo": "OCTOBER",
        "isFavorite": true
    }
}
```

---

```
//Request details using volley for the clicked spot

try {
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            StringRequest requestDetails = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, GET_SPOT_DETAILS,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            try {
                                JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response);
                                SpotInfo.name = result.getString("name");
                                SpotInfo.country = result.getString("country");
                                    /*SpotInfo.latitude = result.getDouble("latitude");
                                    SpotInfo.longitude = result.getDouble("longitude");
                                    SpotInfo.windPbb = result.getDouble("windProbability");*/
                                SpotInfo.whenToGo = result.getString("whenToGo");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Error when parsing all details in JSON.", e);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "OnErrorResponse", error);
                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("spotId", idArray.get(position)); //I think here is the problem

                    return params;
                }
            };
            queue.add(requestDetails);
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SpotInfo.class));
        }
    });
} catch(
Exception e) {
    Log.e("OnItemClick", "OnItemClick error.", e);
}
```

---

```
//Iterating through the spots provided by Get allspots request  

private static ArrayList<KitesurfingSpot> getAllSpotsFromJsonResult(String spotJSON) {

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(spotJSON))
        return null;

    ArrayList<KitesurfingSpot> spots = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(spotJSON);
        JSONArray resultsArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("result");
        for(int i=0; i < resultsArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject spot = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i);
            idStrings.add(spot.getString("id")); //Here I get the id
            String name = spot.getString("name");
            String country = spot.getString("country");

            KitesurfingSpot kitesurfingSpot = new KitesurfingSpot(name, country, R.drawable.star_off);
            spots.add(kitesurfingSpot);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Problem parsing the kitesurfing spot JSON result.", e);
    }

    return spots;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use strong type class and Serialize and De-serialize using the json library instead of interpret the request/response.

you also can use a shared assembler with the contract class ins case you can modify both projects or collaborate with the Author.